# How to configure SublimeREPL for mit-scheme?

Tags: mit-scheme, sublimerepl

I have installed SublimeREPL, and now I am trying to customize the interpreters a bit. How can I add MIT Scheme to the Tools->SublimeREPL menu? I am new to Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can read documentation about **configuring additional REPLs** here:http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#basics-of-language-integration-configuration-and-launch-commands

And take a look at **existing Scheme configuration** here:
https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/tree/master/config/Scheme

Most Scheme/Lisp dialects are quite easy to configure, you should have no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Please allow me to share my experience. Just made it work on my machine.

First, recommend you to install a [SCM](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/SCM.html) implementation of Scheme, which is much easier to config than mit-scheme.

> *If you use windows, the env variable should be added to the system
> automatically after you finished installation.*

Then, open Preferences -> Browse Packages -> SublimeREPL -> config -> Scheme -> Main.sublime-menu.

At last, config this file like this:

[image]

Now it should work. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a good 2 hours, I finally figured out how to get it working in SublimeText 3.

First install the package "Scheme" through package control.

Then install the package "SublimeREPL" (for Sublime Text 2/3).

Then install SCM implementation of scheme as **@mons** mentioned.

Once Done, modify the file shown below.

SublimeText3 >> InstalledPackages >> Scheme.sublime-package (open with Zip software) >> Scheme.sublime-build (modify to the following below)

```
{
    "cmd": ["scm", "-f", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.scheme"
}
```

I realised that my "Scheme" installed through Package Installer was overriding my Sublime Build Settings in the SublimeREPL folder. That's why it didnt work eventhough I modified my settings as **@mons** mentioned. 
Thats it. 
Hope it works.   :)