# MIT-Scheme for SublimeREPL windows

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme, sublimerepl

Getting the error `WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')`

I've tried tinkering with the Main.sublime-menu, but kinda uncertain what path I should be putting so i used variations of `C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe`, including without `mit-scheme.exe` and using "`\\\`" (double) instead of just "`\`" (since that's what was being accepted by sublime which was what i used to edit the file), and also unsure at what point in the Main.sublime-menu I should be altering.

I've read similar solutions, but they're usually in mac where you can easily type which scheme onto the console to get the file path of scheme, so I'm thinking it has to do with me not knowing my correct file path or something? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two env variables to your machine:

> MITSCHEME_BIN_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin
>   MITSCHEME_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib

Config this Main.sublime-menu file like this:

[image]

Then it should work. Enjoy it!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work...I sorta still get the same error but thank you for the suggestion maybe the problem is related to my specific computer or something

Comment: How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496963/how-to-configure-sublimerepl-for-mit-scheme/22192167#22192167

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k6e7dx18354ifgs/Untitled.png      Getting some kind of error still but a different kind