# How to configure Sublime3 for chez scheme?

Tags: scheme, sublimetext3, interpreter, chez-scheme

I have compile chez scheme and installed sublime3 SublimeREPL and scheme in OSX system.

and config as [How to configure SublimeREPL for mit-scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496963/how-to-configure-sublimerepl-for-mit-scheme) topic.

edit SublimeText3 >> InstalledPackages >> Scheme.sublime-package (open with Zip software) >> Scheme.sublime-build (modify to the following below)

```
{
    "cmd": ["scm", "-f", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.scheme"
}
```

I can open chez scheme interpreter in sublimeREPL,but when I want to build file with "Build System: scheme", I got error"[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scheme'", how should I modified Build System code?

[image: Terminal scheme path test]  [image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

The error `"[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scheme'"` means that the system looked for a command `scheme` in your search path (i.e. in the list of folders in which your commands are stored).

First you must check that you have installed Chez Scheme correctly

- open a terminal
- write:  scheme

Do you see something like this:

```
soegaard$ scheme
Chez Scheme Version 9.4
Copyright 1984-2016 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (exit)
```

Then type

```
which scheme
```

to see the path to the `scheme` executable. In my case (also on OS X)
the path is `/usr/local/bin/scheme`.

Next up is to check your search path. In a terminal, type:

```
env| grep PATH
```

The output is something like this:

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/...
```

It is a list of folder separated by colons. Check that the folder in which the `scheme` executable is on the list. If it isn't either make a copy of `scheme` in one of the folder or add your folder to the path.

If you decide to alter the path you may or may not have to restart Sublime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried what you said. I think I had installed chez scheme correctly. I have add picture on my question. Maybe another problem?

Comment: @ryandroll If you look at the last picture, you can see the path that Sublime uses does not contain the folder in which scheme is installed. See this answer for how to set the path Sublime uses. http://superuser.com/questions/448476/setting-os-x-path-variable-for-sublime

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot @soegaard.
The easy way to set the path problem is use Package Control and search for "Fix Mac Path".

and also edit SublimeText3 >> InstalledPackages >> Scheme.sublime-package (open with Zip software) >> Scheme.sublime-build (modify to the following below)

```
{
    "cmd": ["scheme", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.scheme"
}
```

[The correct build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePoJz.png)